# How to install XML::Parser without expat-devel?

Tags: perl, debian, cpan, expat-parser

XML::Parser fails to build on a quite fresh 64-bit Debian box.  After issuing `cpan XML::Parser`, cpan fails with lots of errors about Expat.c and Expat.xs:

```
[...]
Expat.xs:2182: error: ‘CallbackVector’ has no member named ‘skip_until’
Expat.c: In function ‘XS_XML__Parser__Expat_Do_External_Parse’:
Expat.c:2904: error: ‘XML_Parser’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Expat.c:2904: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘parser’
Expat.xs:2194: error: ‘parser’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [Expat.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.41-rpV6ok/Expat'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  TODDR/XML-Parser-2.41.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Message at the start of the output explains that *expat-devel* is needed for building.

> Expat must be installed prior to building XML::Parser and I can't find
>   it in the standard library directories. Install 'expat-devel' package with your
>   OS package manager. See 'README'.

But *expat-devel* is not in Debian repository.

Is it possible to get over this without need to build/install expat from source?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The package you want to install is named `libexpat1-dev`. You could also just install `libxml-parser-perl` via apt-get. Or if you really want to install via CPAN try installing the Debian packages dependencies first via `apt-get build-dep libxml-parser-perl`.

Answer (score 9):

[libexpat1-dev](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libexpat1-dev) contains both libexpat and expat.h, which are both mentioned in the message as well:

> If expat is installed, but in a non-standard directory, then use the
>   following options to Makefile.PL:
>
> EXPATLIBPATH=...  To set the directory in which to find libexpat
>
> EXPATINCPATH=...  To set the directory in which to find expat.h

Installing libexpat1-dev seems to solve the problem:

```
$ aptitude install libexpat1-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

There is always the manual method - to build/install expat from source. 
(This example shows installing to an alternative location for **XAMPP | LAMPP**)

Download from: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/files/expat/

```
tar zxf /[where-ever]/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz -C /tmp
cd /tmp/expat-2.1.0
/opt/lampp/bin/perl ./configure --prefix=/opt/lampp LDFLAGS=-L/opt/lampp/lib 
make
make install
```

http://search.cpan.org - search for and download - XML::Parser

```
tar zxf /[where-ever]/XML-Parser-2.41.tar.gz -C /tmp
cd /tmp/XML-Parser-2.41
/opt/lampp/bin/perl ./Makefile.PL EXPATLIBPATH=/opt/lampp/lib EXPATINCPATH=/opt/lampp/include
make
make test
make install
```

Answer (score 3):

Work like a charm in Ubuntu 15.04. The only thing that I need is install Perl XML Parser with:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl
```

And following the instructions here, I was able to import successfully all my ratings into Rhythmbox. Now, the only work that I need to do is create again the smart play lists, that is nothing compared with my entire libray ratings.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same issue wanting to complile the new GIMP 2.9.4 beta on OSX 10.8 and the aid of homebrew.

First install perl

```
brew install perl
```

Then the XML::Parser module by going into the perl shell with

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

And inside the shell install XML::Parser by typing

```
install XML::Parser
```

Exit shell

```
exit
```

Now, verify it has been installed successfully. If everything is ok, you will not see an error.

```
perl -e "require XML::Parser"
```

If the ./configure still fails missing XML::Parser, then intltools is not using the perl you have installed. Looking at the script tells me it does the test with `$INTLTOOL_PERL -e "require XML::Parser"`. Trying a `echo $INTLTOOL_PERL` gave out nothing, so the magic is to set it with

```
export $INTLTOOL_PERL=perl
```

Now run ./configure again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods worked for me. I had the right environment variables setup but they were somehow not picked up by `cpanm` that I use to install perl modules. Expat was also installed.

Here is what I did to overcome the same problem that OP is reporting.
This is very close to what [@LadyBuzz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10305418/1495326) suggested.

1. Download the `XML::Parser` from `cpan.org`
2. Extract the tarball into directory and descend to it.
3. Open the `Makefile.pl` and edit the first lines to actually have the absolute paths to both: `EXPATLIBPATH` and `EXPATINCPATH`
4. Save the `Makefile.pl`, go up one level and create a new tarball with the `Makefile.pl` that you just edited.
5. Execute `cpanm` on the newly created tarball.

This resulted in successful installation of the module.