# XML::Parser refusing to install

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I've been trying to install XML::Simple on Ubuntu 12.10 for the past two hours or so and have officially run out of ideas. It's failing at the XML::Parser.

I've done an

```
sudo apt-get install expat
```

and it still did not work. Here's the error I've been getting:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/<user>/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.41-MCLo7T/Expat'
cp Expat.pm ../blib/lib/XML/Parser/Expat.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.14.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp -noprototypes -typemap /usr/share /perl/5.14/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Expat.xs > Expat.xsc && mv Expat.xsc Expat.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"2.41\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.41\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE"   Expat.c
Expat.xs:12:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Expat.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sclarawu/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.41-MCLo7T/Expat'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
TODDR/XML-Parser-2.41.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Seems to be telling me that it's unable to find expat.h, but I'm not sure why or how, considering expat is installed? I tried to apt expat-devel, but it appears not to be a package in apt. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT: I seemed to have been simply trying to install the wrong package. -.- It's always the little things. Much thanks to those who answered!

Comment: Why not try the simple and direct 
    perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::Simple'

Comment: Yup, that's what I had been trying and where I'd been getting these errors. Sorry, should have been more clear. All resolved now! Thank you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Another way to get to the same information which @Moritz Bunkus has pointed out above.

```
ubuntu:~$ apt-cache search expat 
expat - XML parsing C library - example application 
libexpat1 - XML parsing C library - runtime library 
libexpat1-dev - XML parsing C library - development kit
```

The third one in the result set is what you are looking for.

Comment: for me on scientific linux I had to intall "expat-devel" as yum search on libexpat revealed nothing but a node.js binding. Thanks for the post, expat-devel got me going and now I can install my perl deps (XML::RSS)!

Answer (score 20):

Adding to the other answers, here's how to install the expat dependency on CentOS/RHEL:

```
yum install expat-devel
```

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 7.  Also can use `dnf install expat-devel` if you prefer `dnf`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to install the Expat library and its development headers. For DebUbuntu this means `libexpat1-dev` as well as those distros often split their libraries into two packages: one for the runtime components (shared libraries, data files, general documentation), one for the development components (static libraries, header files, development documentation).

Comment: +1 to this. I just added a comment below to highlight how to get to it on ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case, using Debian Jessie I had to install `libexpat1-dev` by executing `apt-get install libexpat1-dev`

Comment: Thanks for adding this! It was precisely what I needed right now.

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to install it by downloading it from cpan and manually editing the `Makefile.pl` inside to correctly pointing to the `EXPATLIBPATH` and `EXPATINCPATH`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693031/how-to-install-xmlparser-without-expat-devel/44441248#44441248) for more detailed instructions.